# XHR progress bar for file upload for request AND response

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, azure, xmlhttprequest

I want to show the upload progress of a file through to the **time the request completes from the server**.

Every single example out there just shows how to do a progress bar for sending the file from browser to server and not from browser to server back to browser.

The code I have below only shows the progress of the client uploading the file to the server and not the response. Basically as soon as the request is hit on the server the progress event on the client completes which isn't what I want.

How do I do this?

xhr:

```
export default (url, opts = {}, uploadEvents) =>
  new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open(opts.method || 'get', url, true);

    Object.keys(opts.headers || {}).forEach((key) => {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(key, opts.headers[key]);
    });

    xhr.onload = e => res(e.target.responseText);
    xhr.onerror = rej;

    if (xhr.upload) {
      Object.keys(uploadEvents).forEach((key) => {
        xhr.upload.addEventListener(key, uploadEvents[key]);
      });
    }

    xhr.send(opts.body);
  });
```

Request:

```
fetchProgress('/upload/upload', {
  method: 'post',
  body: formData,
}, {
  progress: (e) => {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      const progressPercent = parseInt((e.loaded / e.total) * 100, 10);

      progressPercents[i] = {
        value: progressPercent,
        id,
      };

      dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_UPLOAD_PROGRESS',
        progressPercents,
      });
    }
  },
});
```

Server code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
{
    var processAudio = await _fileStorage.TempStoreMp3Data(file);
    var audioBlob = _cloudStorage.GetBlob(CloudStorageType.Audio, processAudio.AudioName);

    await audioBlob.UploadFromPathAsync(processAudio.AudioPath, ProcessAudio.AudioContentType);

    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically as soon as the request is hit on the server the progress event on the client completes which isn't what I want.

To get the progress based on server side operation, I suggest you create another action which could return the progress on server side. On client side, you need to invoke this action to get the progress. Code below is for your reference.

On server side, we need to define a Dictionary to store the progresses and we need to use a uploadId to connect the two actions. When invoke these 2 actions, we need to use the same uploadId from client side.

```
//use this dictionary to store the progress for upload
private static Dictionary<string, int> uploadProgresses = new Dictionary<string, int>();

public IActionResult GetUploadProgress(string uploadId)
{
    int progress = 0;
    uploadProgresses.TryGetValue(uploadId, out progress);
    return Content(progress.ToString());
}


[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file, string uploadId)
{
    uploadProgresses.Add(uploadId, 0);
    var processAudio = await _fileStorage.TempStoreMp3Data(file);
    uploadProgresses[uploadId] = 20;
    var audioBlob = _cloudStorage.GetBlob(CloudStorageType.Audio, processAudio.AudioName);
    uploadProgresses[uploadId] = 40;
    await audioBlob.UploadFromPathAsync(processAudio.AudioPath, ProcessAudio.AudioContentType);
    uploadProgresses[uploadId] = 100;
    return Ok();
}
```

Client side code sample.

```
var myVar = window.setInterval(function () { getUploadProgress(); }, 1000);

var uniqualId = uuidv4();

document.getElementById("uuid").innerHTML = uniqualId;

function uuidv4() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });
}

function getUploadProgress() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            //update your progress bar
            document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            if (xhttp.responseText == '100') {
                myStopFunction();
            }
        }
        else if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status != 200)
        { 
            myStopFunction();
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "/Home/GetUploadProgress?uploadId=" + uniqualId, true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function myStopFunction() {
    window.clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

**Update 7/10/2017**

> Should we be using Session to store the upload progress instead of a static dictionary?

No, we can't use Session to store the upload progress. According the lifecycle of ASP.NET application, the state(Session) will be updated after the handler(your Action) be executed. It means the Session will not be updated until your Action executed completed.

[image]

Comment: Should we be using Session to store the upload progress instead of a static dictionary? I tried it with session but the value goes straight to 100 immediately. I'm wondering if it's to do with threading.

Comment: No, we can't use Session to store the upload progress. I will add the detail reason to my reply.

Comment: The problem with this is that the static dictionary keeps the values in memory and doesn't remove them after time. I managed to use session state instead. See my answer. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: We can also remove the uploadProgresses from static dictionary if it reaches 100. Because the client side will clear the internal after got process 100 from server side.

Comment: It's harder to clear it though if an error occurs or the user cancels, whereas session automatically expires.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to do this:

Create one action for every process that you want to update the progress for. This way we can do the entire progress client side and not mess around with session or static variables on the server.

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> TempStoreMp3File(IFormFile file)
{
    var processAudio = await _fileStorage.TempStoreMp3Data(file);

    return Ok(new
    {
        audioName = processAudio.AudioName,
        audioPath = processAudio.AudioPath,
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromBody] UploadViewModel model)
{
    var audioBlob = _cloudStorage.GetBlob(CloudStorageType.Audio, model.AudioName);

    await audioBlob.UploadFromPathAsync(model.AudioPath, ProcessAudio.AudioContentType);

    return Ok();
}

fetchProgress('/upload/tempStoreMp3File', {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData,
    }, {
    readystatechange() {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        dispatch({
          type: 'UPDATE_UPLOAD_PROGRESS',
          progressPercent: 75,
          index: progressIndex,
          message: 'Uploading to SoundVast...',
        });

        fetch('/upload/upload', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: this.responseText,
        }).then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            dispatch({
              type: 'UPDATE_UPLOAD_PROGRESS',
              progressPercent: 100,
              index: progressIndex,
              message: 'Successfully uploaded file.',
            });
          }
        });
      }
    },
    }, {
    load: () => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'UPDATE_UPLOAD_PROGRESS',
        progressPercent: 50,
        index: progressIndex,
        message: 'Converting to mp3...',
      });
    },
    progress: (e) => {
      if (e.lengthComputable) {
        const progressPercent = parseInt((e.loaded / e.total) * 25, 10);

        dispatch({
          type: 'UPDATE_UPLOAD_PROGRESS',
          progressPercent,
          index: progressIndex,
          message: 'Sending file to server...',
        });
      }
    },
});
```

fetchProgress:

```
export default (url, opts = {}, events, uploadEvents) =>
  new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open(opts.method || 'get', url, true);

    Object.keys(opts.headers || {}).forEach((key) => {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(key, opts.headers[key]);
    });

    xhr.onload = e => res(e.target.responseText);
    xhr.onerror = rej;

    Object.keys(events).forEach((key) => {
      xhr.addEventListener(key, events[key]);
    });

    if (xhr.upload) {
      Object.keys(uploadEvents).forEach((key) => {
        xhr.upload.addEventListener(key, uploadEvents[key]);
      });
    }

    xhr.send(opts.body);
  });
```